# how to train knn model with validation data in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

So I have
(Xa, Ya): data training
(Xv Yv): data_validation
(Xt, Yt): data_test
so I want to apply knn with different value of neighbors (1 to 25) to plot in one same graph the errors of classification for data training and data_validation the only solution that I found is using cross-validation but I look for another solution without cross-validation

Comment: k-NN does not require any training:

> k-NN is a type of classification where the function is only approximated locally and all computation is deferred until function evaluation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

this may be a very simple example to design possible modifications:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

for i in range(1,26):
    cls = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    cls.fit(Xa, ya)
    y_probs = cls.predict_proba(Xv)
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(yv, y_probs[:,1])
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i got this error message ; :ValueError: y_true takes value in {1, 2} and pos_label is not specified: either make y_true take value in {0, 1} or {-1, 1} or pass pos_label explicitly.

Comment: I think, it may be about your class labels. Are your labels 1-2 or 0-1, or do you have multi-label?